# ServerSocket reuseAddress allow bind to an already bound port?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, tcp

When using [Netty](http://jboss.org/netty), I was surprised that if I use reuseAddress option, it allows a ServerSocket to bind to the same address without raising an "already bind exception"

```
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(
                new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors
                        .newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));
        bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
            @Override
            public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
                ChannelPipeline p = pipeline();
                p.addLast("handler", new DummyHandler());
                return p;
            }
        });
        bootstrap.setOption("reuseAddress", true);
        bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(2000));
        bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(2000));
```

I just thought that reuseAddress allows a new socket to reuse a close-wait socket, but this is different. The following is the result of a netstat command

```
  C:\Users\secmask>netstat -a -n|grep 2000
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

Am I missing something? What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that Windows allows this due to history.  It is a bit of a security issue.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740618 for some information about how the involved options interact.  Which socket gets a connection is undefined.  Maybe if you narrow down the version of Windows you are using you could narrow down what the response will be although it is probably just to not depend on it.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is what `reuseAddress` is supposed to do.  Multiple sockets can be bound to the same IP/Port at the same time, regardless of their states.

Comment: when new income client connect to this port, which of that duplicate socket will accept the client? could you provide some documents, links about this?

Comment: When multiple sockets are bound to the same IP/Port at the same time, their behavior is undefined.  Anything can happen.  There is no way to predict it.  It is VERY bad practice to do this for exactly this reason.  `reuseAddress` should only be used when you have bound your own socket, then closed it, and need to reopen the same IP/Port for a new socket before the old socket has finished any wait states when you are sure that no more data will arrive for the old socket.